# Expect command: Setting multi-line environment variable of host

Tags: shell-script, expect

So I have an RSA token set in my environment variable.
I want to set it in the environment of the remote machine.
I tried this below script to set, but it only sets first line `-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----`:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

spawn ssh -tt ec2-user@$::env(EC2_INSTANCE)

send "export RSA_KEY=$::env(MY_KEY)\r"
expect -re ".*\$"
```

How can I set the whole content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put its value in single quotes:

```
send "export RSA_KEY='$::env(MY_KEY)'\r"
expect -re {.*\$}
```

Notice the `{.*\$}` instead of `".*\$"`; Your `".*\$"` will turn into `.*$` and match *anything*, including the empty string.

If the `MY_KEY` environment variable can contain `'`s, you may want to escape them:

```
send "export RSA_KEY='[regsub -all {'} $::env(MY_KEY) {'\''}]'\r"
expect -re {.*\$}
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked.